# Mobile Phone emulator

Tags: mobile, emulation, mobile-website

Is there a good all in one emulator for testing mobile websites. Just using 'media queries and need to test on predominantly iphone, blackberry, android, and windows 7 phones.

Many thanks,
C

Comment: [Look at this list](http://www.mobilexweb.com/emulators).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no one solution that will work on all these platforms however the SDKs for all include simulators/emulators and the best part is that all but for the iPhone are free.

[BlackBerry Simulators](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/downloads/simulators/)
[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html)
[Windows Phone 7 Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402563(v=VS.92).aspx)
The iPhone SDK also includes a simulator (Mac only) but if you need to test on a PC, you can do a pretty good job using http://iphone4simulator.com/ running in Safari for Windows.

As with all simulator/emulator usage, these are good for initial testing but you need to use an actual device to get true results.

Also note that different BlackBerry devices use different default browsers. Android devices also use varying versions of WebKit so you may see some variation between actual devices which isn't shown in the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Matt's reply, I think you should also test the different browsers available for smartphones.

For example the popular Opera mobile: http://www.opera.com/mobile/demo/

Answer (score 1):

You might find http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ very useful for testing mobile websites on different screen sizes.  It's not as true as a native emulator, but it allows you to test several phones, tablets, etc. at one site and you don't have to install any software.

Comment: I tried this with my mobile site, and it doesn't appear to read the javascript that creates my mobile viewport meta tag. Or it may not even acknowledge meta tags at all

Answer (score 0):

try http://www.browserstack.com/. This one is not free, but it gives a trial period of 30 minutes for each account we create

Answer (score 0):

[Try Mobile web browser emulator](http://www.kythuatmang.net/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php) this free tools help you testing mobile websites

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to simulate the mobile device user agent and screen resolutions, also check out chrome's mobile device simulator https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode#enable-device-mode